# How to grep asterisk without escaping?

Tags: bash, grep, escaping

Suppose I have a file `abc.txt` which contains line `ab*cd`. When I `grep` that pattern `ab*cd` with quotes but without escaping the asterisk it does not work:

```
> grep ab*c abc.txt 
> grep "ab*c" abc.txt 
> grep 'ab*c' abc.txt
```

When I use *both* quotes and escaping it *does* work

```
> grep "ab\*c" abc.txt 
ab*cd
> grep 'ab\*c' abc.txt 
ab*cd
```

Now I wonder why the quotes do not work and if I can use *only* quotes without escaping the asterisk.

Comment: You can also use a character class to match a literal asterisk. Because square brackets have a meaning in the shell, too, you still need to quote the expression; `grep 'ab[*]c' abc.txt`

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? If you intend to use the shell, you need to understand metacharacters and quoting, not avoid them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the flag `-F` to search for fixed strings -- instead of regular expressions. From `man grep`:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  list  of  fixed strings, separated by
          newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F  is  specified  by
          POSIX.)
```

For example:

```
$ grep -F "ab*c" <<< "ab*c"
ab*c
```

Answer (score 7):

first of all, you should keep in mind: `regex =/= glob`

`*` has special meaning in regex. You have to escape it to match it literally. without escaping the `*`, grep tries to match `ab+(any number of b)+c`

for example:

`abbbbbbbbbbbbc`